# Concatenate multiple tokens for X macro

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor, x-macros

I'm trying to use X macros and preprocessor concatenation, both for the first time, together.

I've read a lot of the other questions on SO related to preprocessor concatenation but not yet been able to wrap my head around them or how to adapt those to my use case.

The list of items is a list of ID numbers for a bunch of `structs`, like so:

```
#define LIST_OF_ID_NUMS \
    X(1) \
    X(2) \
    X(3) \
    X(4) \
    X(5) \
    X(6) \
    X(7) \
    X(8) \
    X(9) \
    X(10) \
    X(11)
```

I can declare the structs like so:

```
#define X(id_num) static myFooStruct foo_## id_num ;
LIST_OF_ID_NUMS 
#undef X
// gives: 'struct myFooStruct foo_n;' where 'n' is an ID number
```

Now I would also like to initialise one of the members of each struct to be equal to the ID number, such that `foo_n.id = n;`. I have been able to achieve the first token concatenation, by using the following:

```
#define X(id_num) foo_## id_num .id = 3 ;
LIST_OF_ID_NUMS 
#undef X
// gives: 'foo_n.id = x' where 'x' is some constant (3 in this case)
```

But I have not been able to understand how to correctly expand the idea further so that the assigned value is also replaced. I have tried:

```
#define X(id_num) foo_## id_num .id = ## id_num ;
LIST_OF_ID_NUMS 
#undef X
// Does NOT give: 'foo_n.id = n;' :(
```

And various attempts at using double indirection for the concatenation. But have not been successful. The above attempt resulting in errors like the following for each item in the `LIST_OF_ID_NUMS`:

```
foo.c:47:40: error: pasting "=" and "1" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  #define X(id_num) foo_## id_num .id = ## id_num ;
                                    ^
foo.c:10:5: note: in expansion of macro 'X'
  X(1) \
  ^
foo.c:48:2: note: in expansion of macro 'LIST_OF_ID_NUMS '
  LIST_OF_ID_NUMS
```

How can I best achieve the form `foo_n.id = n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that should simply be :

```
#define X(id_num) foo_## id_num .id = id_num ;
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Darn, this means I understand even less than I thought about preprocessor concatenation :\

Comment: @Toby You need token-pasting here to get `foo_42` (one token) instead of `foo_ 42` (two tokens, and a syntax error later). But `=42` does not have to be a single token (and can't, in fact, be one), so no token-pasting here.

Comment: Ahh, light dawns! Thanks @Quentin