# X-Macro with concatenation parameter

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, x-macros

I am using X-Macro to create enumerations using the following code

```
#define WIDGET_OFFSETS                                                               \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_HEIGHT_WA, 1, OFFSET_HEIGHT_WB, 2, OFFSET_HEIGHT_WC, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_WIDTH_WA,  1, OFFSET_WIDTH_WB,  2, OFFSET_WIDTH_WC,  3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_LENGTH_WA, 1, OFFSET_LENGTH_WB, 2, OFFSET_LENGTH_WC, 3)


#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d, e, f) a = b,
typedef enum { WIDGET_OFFSETS } Offsets_WA_e;
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET
```

I would like to generalize this a bit more such that the X-Macro table only have four parameters.  The first parameter is the general/base name then have it concatenation with additional parameter.  I have defined the macros as the following which is trying to accomplish the code just shown.

```
#define WIDGET_OFFSETS                         \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_HIEGHT_, 1, 2, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_WIDTH_,  1, 2, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_LENGTH_, 1, 2, 3)

#define EXPAND_NAME(x,y)   x##y
#define EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(z) typedef enum { WIDGET_OFFSETS } Offsets_##z_e;

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d) EXPAND_NAME(a,WA) = b,
EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(WA)
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET
```

The compiler provides me with the following error message:

> error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token

So, it seems my problem is at the "EXPAND_NAME(a, WA) = b," expression.  I have tried a couple of different approaches, but none work so far.  Lastly and  ideally, I would like to only specify "WA", "WB" and "WC" once and not twice as the code here does.

I did find a similar question, [Concatenate multiple tokens for X macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501401/concatenate-multiple-tokens-for-x-macro), but not quite what I would like to do, if possible. Any insight to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit: Corrected the first X-Macro definition as it contained copy/paste errors

Comment: Note in passing that 'height' has the e before the i (a counter-example to the old "i before e except after c" adage, along with 'weight' and 'neighbour' and some others).

Comment: In your first block of code, the first column has 'height', 'width' and 'length', but the third and fifth columns have 'height' only — is that a copy'n'paste error with incomplete editing after the paste?  If it isn't meant to more consistent, you have no chance with X-macro.

Comment: Could you please post what input you would use and what output you would expect?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the problem but in the definition `#define EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(z) typedef enum { WIDGET_OFFSETS } Offsets_##z_e` you probably wanted `#define EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(z) typedef enum { WIDGET_OFFSETS } Offsets_##z##_e`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffle, please forgive my copy/paste errors and spelling.  I came up with an example rather quickly than use my real code.  In my haste, I failed to proof read my question, so I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Marian, I didn't realize that the 'z' need to have ## before and after.  After seeing your response, it makes sense now and that is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix first code block

Your first example code should be using WIDTH and LENGTH consistently in the third and fourth lines of the macro:

```
#define WIDGET_OFFSETS                                                               \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_HEIGHT_WA, 1, OFFSET_HEIGHT_WB, 2, OFFSET_HEIGHT_WC, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_WIDTH_WA,  1, OFFSET_WIDTH_WB,  2, OFFSET_WIDTH_WC,  3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_LENGTH_WA, 1, OFFSET_LENGTH_WB, 2, OFFSET_LENGTH_WC, 3)

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d, e, f) a = b,
typedef enum { WIDGET_OFFSETS } Offsets_WA_e;
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET
#undef WIDGET_OFFSETS
```

With noise lines and repeated blank lines omitted, that yields:

```
typedef enum { OFFSET_HEIGHT_WA = 1, OFFSET_WIDTH_WA = 1, OFFSET_LENGTH_WA = 1, } Offsets_WA_e;
```

#### Fix second code block

Your second example had problems, notably it used `Offsets_ ## z_e` in place of the `Offsets_ ## z ## _e` shown below.  It is also usually best to leave semicolons off the end of a macro definition and to leave them to appear after the macro invocation.  That's a guideline; there are exceptions aplenty.

```
#define WIDGET_OFFSETS                        \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_HEIGHT, 1, 2, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_WIDTH,  1, 2, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(OFFSET_LENGTH, 1, 2, 3)

#define EXPAND_NAME(x,y)   x ## _ ## y
#define EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(z) typedef enum { WIDGET_OFFSETS } Offsets_ ## z ## _e

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d) EXPAND_NAME(a,WA) = b,
EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(WA);
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d) EXPAND_NAME(a,WB) = c,
EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(WB);
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d) EXPAND_NAME(a,WC) = d,
EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(WC);
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET

#undef WIDGET_OFFSETS
#undef EXPAND_ENUM
#undef EXPAND_NAME
```

That produced:

```
typedef enum { OFFSET_HEIGHT_WA = 1, OFFSET_WIDTH_WA = 1, OFFSET_LENGTH_WA = 1, } Offsets_WA_e;

typedef enum { OFFSET_HEIGHT_WB = 2, OFFSET_WIDTH_WB = 2, OFFSET_LENGTH_WB = 2, } Offsets_WB_e;

typedef enum { OFFSET_HEIGHT_WC = 3, OFFSET_WIDTH_WC = 3, OFFSET_LENGTH_WC = 3, } Offsets_WC_e;
```

#### Avoid repeating the suffixes

Your concern is that the suffixes WA, WB and WC are repeated in the code, and you'd rather not repeat yourself like that.  It is possible to work around it. One way of doing it is to pass an argument to the `WIDGET_OFFSETS` macro, like this:

```
#define WIDGET_OFFSETS(sx)                    \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(EXPAND_NAME(OFFSET_HEIGHT, sx), 1, 2, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(EXPAND_NAME(OFFSET_WIDTH,  sx), 1, 2, 3)  \
     X_WIDGET_OFFSET(EXPAND_NAME(OFFSET_LENGTH, sx), 1, 2, 3)

#define EXPAND_NAME(x,y)   x ## _ ## y
#define EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(z) typedef enum { WIDGET_OFFSETS(z) } Offsets_ ## z ## _e

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d) a = b,
EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(WA);
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d) a = c,
EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(WB);
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET

#define X_WIDGET_OFFSET(a, b, c, d) a = d,
EXPAND_ENUM_TYPE(WC);
#undef X_WIDGET_OFFSET

#undef WIDGET_OFFSETS
#undef EXPAND_ENUM
#undef EXPAND_NAME
```

This yields the following, which is the same as before, but the WA, WB, and WC only appears once each in the source.

```
typedef enum { OFFSET_HEIGHT_WA = 1, OFFSET_WIDTH_WA = 1, OFFSET_LENGTH_WA = 1, } Offsets_WA_e;

typedef enum { OFFSET_HEIGHT_WB = 2, OFFSET_WIDTH_WB = 2, OFFSET_LENGTH_WB = 2, } Offsets_WB_e;

typedef enum { OFFSET_HEIGHT_WC = 3, OFFSET_WIDTH_WC = 3, OFFSET_LENGTH_WC = 3, } Offsets_WC_e;
```